# Possibilities for structuring ingested json data using Nifi

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-nifi, hortonworks-sandbox

Is it possible, using Nifi, to load a json file into a structured table?

I've called the following weather forecast data (from 6000 weather stations), which i'm currently loading into HDFS. It all appears on one line:

```
{"SiteRep":{"Wx":{"Param":[{"name":"F","units":"C","$":"Feels Like Temperature"},{"name":"G","units":"mph","$":"Wind Gust"},{"name":"H","units":"%","$":"Screen Relative Humidity"},{"name":"T","units":"C","$":"Temperature"},{"name":"V","units":"","$":"Visibility"},{"name":"D","units":"compass","$":"Wind Direction"},{"name":"S","units":"mph","$":"Wind Speed"},{"name":"U","units":"","$":"Max UV Index"},{"name":"W","units":"","$":"Weather Type"},{"name":"Pp","units":"%","$":"Precipitation Probability"}]},"DV":{"dataDate":"2017-01-12T22:00:00Z","type":"Forecast","Location":[{"i":"14","lat":"54.9375","lon":"-2.8092","name":"CARLISLE AIRPORT","country":"ENGLAND","continent":"EUROPE","elevation":"50.0","Period":{"type":"Day","value":"2017-01-13Z","Rep":{"D":"WNW","F":"-3","G":"25","H":"67","Pp":"0","S":"13","T":"2","V":"EX","W":"1","U":"1","$":"720"}}},{"i":"22","lat":"53.5797","lon":"-0.3472","name":"HUMBERSIDE AIRPORT","country":"ENGLAND","continent":"EUROPE","elevation":"24.0","Period":{"type":"Day","value":"2017-01-13Z","Rep":{"D":"NW","F":"-2","G":"43","H":"63","Pp":"3","S":"25","T":"4","V":"EX","W":"3","U":"1","$":"720"}}}, .....
```

Ideally, I want the schema structuring into a 6000 row table.

I've tried writing a schema to pass the above into Pig, but haven't been successful, probably because I'm not familiar enough with json to translate this correctly.

Casting around for an easy way to add some structure to the data, I've spotted that there's a PutHBaseJson processor in Nifi.

Can anyone advise if this PutHBaseJson processor would work with the above data structure? And if so, can anyone point me towards a decent tutorial to give me a starting point on the configuration?

Greatly appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`SplitJson`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitJson/) processor to split the 6000 record JSON structure into 6000 individual flowfiles. If you need to "inject" the parameter definitions from the top-level response, you can do a [`ReplaceText`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceText/) or [`JoltTransformJSON`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/) operation to manipulate the individual JSON records. Here is a [good article](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/44726/json-to-json-simplified-with-apache-nifi-and-jolt.html) by Yolanda Davis describing how to perform Jolt transforms (JSON -> JSON) in NiFi.

Once you have the individual flowfiles containing a single JSON record, putting them into HBase is very easy. Bryan Bende wrote an [article describing the necessary configurations](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/storing_syslog_events_in_hbase) for the `PutHBaseJson` processor.

Comment: Many thanks @Andy for providing this information - it's looks to be exactly what I require. I'll experiment over the next couple of days and post back my results.